# How to set a height to a TextField?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a `TextField` which is 40px tall and has a rounded rectangle as background. Can't believe there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this.

Here's what I tried:

- Set the height in a `Container` parent. Doesn't work, the child draws itself over the parent's bounds.
- Set `expands: true`, which requires `maxLines: null`. See the code below. This works but I want to limit the number of lines to 1.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  height: 40,
  child: TextField(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    expands: true,
    maxLines: null,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.all(8),
      border: InputBorder.none,
      isDense: true,
    ),
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set `minLines: 1,` ?

Comment: This is required to be `null` if `expands: true`.

Comment: Try using `sizedBox`, which forcefully sizes its child. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html

Comment: Doesn't work either. I found a workaround, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround, set vertical padding like this:

`contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9)`

To find the specific value (9 in this case), slowly increase it from 0, hot reload and watch the text move down. At some point, the text starts moving back up. Pick the vertical padding that makes the text as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this , and its work well.

```
Row(children: [ Flexible(flex:2,
    child:
      Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  height: 40,
  child:  TextField(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),

    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.all(8),
      border: InputBorder.none,
      isDense: true,
    ),
  )))])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Wrap Your `Textfield` with `SizeBox` Widget and set height according to your design like below
```

```html
SizedBox(
    height: 45,
    child: TextField(
      autocorrect: autocorrect,
      enabled: enabled,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      obscureText: obscure,
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      style: AppTheme.textFieldTextStyle(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        contentPadding: textFieldPadding(),
        prefixIcon: perfixIcon,
        hintText: hint,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        hintStyle: AppTheme.textFieldHintTextStyle()
            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxLength)],
      onTap: onTap,
      onSubmitted: onSubmit,
    ),
  );
```